# Button to return to MainActivity and end all running children activities

Tags: android, button, android-intent

I have read up about closing the current activity and returning to the main activity via activity stacks etc but unfortunately I keep receiving a NullPointer because I need to close the child activities that my class Game is creating.

Here is the class "Game":

```
package pap.crowslanding;


public class Game extends MainActivity implements OnClickListener {
private MazeBall ball;
protected static GameView gameV;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.tester1);
    Button settings = (Button) findViewById(R.id.settingsButton);
    Button mainMenu = (Button) findViewById(R.id.backButton);

    ball = (MazeBall) findViewById(R.id.mazeball);
    gameV = (GameView) findViewById(R.id.game_view);

    settings.setOnClickListener(this);
       mainMenu.setOnClickListener(this);

      //Unrequired code removed

    // IF USER PRESSES ON !Main Menu!
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()){
        case R.id.settingsButton:

        break;
        case R.id.backButton:
            onBackPressed();
        break;
    }
    }

public void onBackPressed() {
    this.finish();//try activityname.finish instead of this
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    startActivity(intent);
}
}
```

My Layout, `R.Layout.tester1` is a custom layout which runs a class GameView and MazeBall, which you can see within the `onCreate` method, my NullPointer refers to the GameView trying to access its `onDraw()` method because it's still running when I want to go to my MainActivity.

Long story short, anyway to terminate these processes? I can't use finish() in the standard sense because GameView does not extend Activity.

Comment: Won't work, even when using in conjunction with `(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)`

Answer (score 0):

I think you can put each Launch Activity in a Stack, Every time you return to your Main Activity.

Here is a Class that I used to manager all of my activity in one of my app, everytime i enter a activity, in it's onCreate method I call its addActivity() method to put the activity into the stack. everytime i quick a activity, in its onDestory method, I call the Manager's finishActivity method to finish the lastest input activity in stack. In you case, I think you can create a method to popup and finish all activities that enter the Stack later than the MainActivity and call the method everytime you return to the MainActivity.

public class AppManager {

```
private static Stack<Activity> activityStack;
private static AppManager instance;

private AppManager(){
}

public static AppManager getInstance() {
    if(instance == null)
        instance = new AppManager();
    return instance;
}

public void addActivity(Activity ac) {
    if(activityStack == null)
        activityStack = new Stack<Activity>();
    activityStack.add(ac);
}

public Activity getCurrentActivity(){
    if(activityStack == null)
        return null;
    return activityStack.lastElement();
}

public void finishActivity(Activity ac) {
    if(activityStack != null && ac != null){
        activityStack.remove(ac);
        ac.finish();
        ac = null;
    }
}

public void finishActivity() {
    if(activityStack != null) {
        Activity ac = activityStack.lastElement();
        finishActivity(ac);
    }
}

public void finishActivity(Class<?> cls) {
    if(activityStack == null)
        return;
    for(Activity ac: activityStack){
        if(ac.getClass().equals(cls)){
            finishActivity(ac);
        }
    }
}

public void finishAllActivity(){
    if(activityStack == null)
        return;
    Activity ac;
    for(int i = 0, size = activityStack.size(); i < size; i ++) {
        ac = activityStack.get(i);
        if(ac != null) {
            ac.finish();
        }
    }
    activityStack.clear();
}

public void appExit(Context context) {
    try {
        finishAllActivity();
        System.exit(0);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("AppManager", "exit error:" + e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You need activity context if its non activity class. Pass the context to the constructor  of the non activity class. Use the context to start the activity.

```
context.startActivity(myIntent);
```

You need to clear the activity back stack.

```
    case R.id.backButton:
        onBackPressed();
    break;


public void onBackPressed() {
Intent myIntent = new Intent(MyActivity.this, MainActivity.class)
myIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity(myIntent);
finish();
return;
}
```

Comment: Is there no way of simply just entering some form of 'finish()' method on my GameView which extends SurfaceView, that is the problem